# Cannot install ruby version on redhat

Tags: redhat, ruby, redmine

I have the following problem and whatever I try, nothing helps. I hope someone could help me with this.

I have a redhat server and I'm trying to install redmine on it. Redmine needs Ruby >= 1.8.7 to run so I installed it and when I execute ruby -v in the console it says I have version 1.8.7 (so that's great)

```
[root@vms redmine]# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-05-31 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
```

But when i try to install the passenger gem I need to run redmine on Apache it says I don't have ruby 1.8.7

```
[root@vms redmine]# gem install passenger
ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
rake requires Ruby version >= 1.8.6
```

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Using vendor build ruby packages is an exercise in frustration.

For anything with ruby it's easier just to use [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) and build a virtual environment. You can then build exactly what you need and have an environment you can replicate reliably. Also you won't end up clobbering your vendor's Ruby install.

Answer (score 0):

Is gem associated with the right ruby?  gem could be using the /etc/alternatives system, and the symlink for gem may be pointing at the older ruby, if that was installed on the system. If it's not using /etc/alternatives, your gem may belong to the older set of ruby packages for RedHat, and you will need to install the rubygems package for the 1.8.7 package.

How did you install ruby?

Oh, what version of RedHat?